# Separated List with id's of related columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's assume the following table:

```
| id         | firstname   | secondname   | group        |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
| 1          | Tom         | Test1        | 111          |
| 2          | Jack        | Test2        | 222          |
| 3          | Chris       | Test3        | 333          |
| 4          | Lucy        | Test4        | 333          |
| 5          | Joe         | Test5        | 111          |
| 6          | John        | Test6        | 111          |
```

how can i get a Query with the information, which others are in the same group?

I want to get something like this:

```
| id         | firstname   | secondname   | group        | others       |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|:------------:|:------------:|
| 1          | Tom         | Test1        | 111          | 5,6          |
| 2          | Jack        | Test2        | 222          |              |
| 3          | Chris       | Test3        | 333          | 4            |
| 4          | Lucy        | Test4        | 333          | 3            |
| 5          | Joe         | Test5        | 111          | 1,6          |
| 6          | John        | Test6        | 111          | 1,5          |
```

it would also be ok, if the separated list also includes the related id itself.

i tried this one, but i got only one row with all ids in the "others"-column

```
Select A.id,A.firstname,A.secondname,A.group,GROUP_CONCAT(B.id) from myTable A
        inner join myTable B
        on (A.group = B.group)
        where a.id <> b.id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select a.*,
       (select group_concat(b.id)
        from mytable b
        where b.group = a.group and b.id <> a.id
       ) as OthersInGroup
from myTable a;
```

Note:  `group` is a keyword and a reserved word in MySQL, so I hope that is not the real name of the column.

A correlated subquery seems simpler than a `left join` and aggregation.  With an index on `mytable(group, id)` it should have pretty good performance too.